# MongoDB Query by DateTime with Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to query MongoDB and return records that have the date of 12/6/2017. The date is in this format:

```
u'Date': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 6, 15, 9, 21, 303000)
```

So, how do I query just the year, month, and day of that entry?  I have tried:

```
date = db.data.find({ 'Date' : {'2017, 12, 6'} },{'Date' : '1'})
for document in date:
     print(date)
```

Which returns: "InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: set(['2017, 12, 6'])".

I also tried:

```
date = db.data.find({ 'Date' : {datetime('2017, 12, 6')} },{'Date' : '1'})
for document in date:
    print(date)
```

Which returns: "NameError: name 'datetime' is not defined".

UPDATE...SOLUTION
I was putting the date into Mongo incorrectly. I'm now putting the date into Mongo with Python like this:

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser

# the date
now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
day = now.day
theDate = str(year) + "-" + str(month) + "-" + str(day)
dateStr = theDate
date = dateutil.parser.parse(dateStr)
# Then put that date into your Mongo insert
```

This is how I'm querying by date. This pulls documents inserted after yersterday (today).

```
import dateutil.parser, datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
yesterday = now.day - 1
dateStr = str(year) + "-" + str(month) + "-" + str(yesterday)
date = dateutil.parser.parse(dateStr)

cursor = db.data.find({'Date' : { '$gt' : date}},{'Date':'1'})
for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say the object is stored as datetime.datetime, to what are you referring? A custom object?

Per the Mongo docs, this is the only date object they support explicity:
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/Date/

From the Docs:

> Date() Returns a date either as a string or as a Date object.
>
> Date() returns the current date as a string in the mongo shell. new
>   Date() returns the current date as a Date object. The mongo shell
>   wraps the Date object with the ISODate helper. The ISODate is in UTC.
>   You can specify a particular date by passing to the Date() method a
>   datetime string. For example:
>
> new Date("") which returns the ISODate with the specified
>   date. new Date("") which specifies the datetime
>   in local datetime and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime
>   in UTC. new Date("") which specifies the
>   datetime in UTC and returns the ISODate with the specified datetime in
>   UTC.

To create a query to search on a Date field in mongo, you would instatiate an ISODate like this

```
db.collection.find({"datefield" : ISODate("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS")})
```

Generally, this will be of somewhat limited use, since the time is measured in milliseconds, so you'll likely need to do a range query similar to:

```
db.collection.find({"datefield" : {"$gte" : <beginning_of_day_as_ISODate>, "$lte" : <end_of_day_as_ISODate>})
```

For example:

```
{createdDate : {$gte : ISODate("2017-12-06T00:00:00"), $lte : ISODate("2017-12-06T23:59:59")}}
```

If you *are* using a custom date object, or storing the date in some non-standard format, your query will need to be tailored to that object.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. Before inserting these records, I defined the date like this: date = datetime.now().   I will update this to what the Mongo docs say.

Comment: It just needed to be changed to: date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

Answer (score 0):

You can try out something like this

```
date = db.data.find({ 'Date' : {new ISODate("2017-12-6T23:59:59Z") } },{'Date' : '1'})

for document in date: 
print(date)
```

Or you could try out this,

```
date = db.data.find({ 'Date' : {new Date(2017,12,6) } },{'Date' : '1'})
for document in date: 
    print(date)
```

Comment: Thank you, Anirudh. Unfortunately these two didn't work. I was defining date as: date = datetime.now(), and I think I need to change that to what the Mongo docs suggest.